# Get a "Docker desktop stopping..." when trying to start Docker on Winodws 10

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I am new to Docker and trying to set it up on my Windows 10 machine. I installed Docker Desktop but when I run it, I get this "Docker desktop stopping..." message rightaway and Docker doesn't seem to start. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For someone who is new to Docker like me - it turned out that I missed two things: 1) I need to run install Docker Desktop as a administritor, and 2) I need to also install a Linux kurnal for 64bit windows system. As soon as I did those, my issue was fixed.

Comment: Did you reinstall the docker after linux install ? As I have followed both the above steps and still get Docker Desktop Stopping - message after I run the docker as administrator. Can you please suggest.

Comment: Not sure if the linux install is necessary. Some says it is not. Have you restarted you machine after reinstall?

Comment: Hi Alexu, did my answer below help? If so, please accept it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using Windows. To fix it, I had to make sure WSL 2 was installed properly:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package

If it's already installed on your machine, try uninstalling and reinstalling it.

However, I can see that people have already mentioned that solution. If you've done it and it didn't work, try this as well:

Open Docker Desktop and click on the 'troubleshoot' icon in the top right corner. Click 'Clean/Purge Data' and select 'WSL 2' only and click 'delete'. Then restart your machine and it should work. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded Docker Desktop 4.26.1. After installation i encountered "Docker Engine Stopped". What worked for me is, i uninstalled and installed once again. It worked.